# SQL Optimization - 3 Tables - Multiple SUMs - 20k records - 12 Seconds

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 3 tables for orders.

```
1-) orders

orderID ⎜odate ⎜ fullname ⎜address ⎜ ordersum ⎜ status_id

2-) order_products

id ⎜orderID ⎜count⎜ psum ⎜cost

3-) order_sum

orderID ⎜shipping ⎜tax ⎜coupon ⎜ discount
```

With the order below, I get "discount / order value / sum of products / sum of taxes" by date. But the query takes 12 seconds for 20000 records. How can I optimize it?

```
SELECT
    DATE(o.odate) AS ODate,
    COUNT(o.orderID) AS OTotal,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(op.psum)
        FROM
            order_products op
        INNER JOIN orders oo ON oo.orderID = op.orderID
        WHERE
            DATE(oo.odate) = DATE(o.odate)
        AND oo.status_id NOT IN (24, 26, 27, 28, 29)
    ) AS ProductSum,
    SUM(os.shipping) / 118 * 100 AS Shipping,
    SUM(os.tax) AS Tax,
    SUM(o.ordersum) AS allPayments,
    SUM(os.coupon) AS CouponDiscount,
    SUM(os.discount) AS Discount,
    (
        SUM(o.ordersum) / COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderID)
    ) AS BasketAVG
FROM
    orders o
JOIN order_sum os ON os.orderID = o.orderID
WHERE
    o.status_id NOT IN (24, 26, 27, 28, 29)
AND o.odate BETWEEN '2014-12-01'
AND '2014-12-30'
GROUP BY
    DATE(o.odate)
ORDER BY
    o.odate ASC;
```

Exlpand:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys   | key       | key_len | ref                         | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | o     | ALL    | PRIMARY,orders  | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                        | 10645 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | os    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ordersum| PRIMARY   | 4       | cikolat_system.o.orderID    |     1 |                                              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | oo    | ALL    | PRIMARY,orders  | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                        | 10645 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | op    | ref    | oproducts2      | oproducts2| 5       | cikolat_system.oo.orderID   |     1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81c921/1

Comment: if possible, can you please provide some sample data on sqlfiddle.com for testing ?

Comment: try to remove `ProductSum` column from query and note down the time. if it will decrease the time, you should think about alternative of sub query. :)

Comment: I concur with Vishal: its likely the correlated subquery in the SELECT list is consuming significant resources. A join to an inline view may improve performance. And a suitable index on the orders table will enabled a more efficient range scan operation, rather than a full scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you ditch the correlated subquery in the SELECT list, and use a join operation to an inline view. I'd write the query like this:

```
SELECT DATE(o.odate)                AS ODate
     , COUNT(o.orderID)             AS OTotal
     , ps.ProductSum                AS ProductSum
     , SUM(os.shipping) / 118 * 100 AS Shipping
     , SUM(os.tax)                  AS Tax
     , SUM(o.ordersum)              AS allPayments
     , SUM(os.coupon)               AS CouponDiscount
     , SUM(os.discount)             AS Discount
     , SUM(o.ordersum)
       / COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderID)  AS BasketAVG
  FROM orders o
  JOIN order_sum os
    ON os.orderID = o.orderID
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT op.orderID
              , SUM(op.psum) AS ProductSum
           FROM order_products op
          GROUP BY op.orderID 
       ) ps
    ON ps.orderID = o.orderID
 WHERE o.status_id NOT IN (24, 26, 27, 28, 29)
   AND o.odate BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-30'
 GROUP BY DATE(o.odate)
 ORDER BY DATE(o.odate) ASC
```

---

Explain output will show the derived table; with MySQL 5.5 and earlier that will be unindexed.

If the rows retrieved from `orders` table is a small subset of the entire table, then an appropriate index on the `orders` table may allow MySQL to make use of an index range scan operation:

```
... ON orders (odate, status)
```

And, again, if that's a small subset of rows from the table, then a JOIN operation within the inline view query would produce a much smaller derived table, and that may improve performance. Repeat the predicates on the `orders` table within the inline view query, e.g.:

```
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT op.orderID
              , SUM(op.psum) AS ProductSum
           FROM order_products op
           JOIN orders oo
             ON oo.orderID = op.orderID
          WHERE oo.status_id NOT IN (24, 26, 27, 28, 29)
            AND oo.odate BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-30'
          GROUP BY op.orderID
       ) ps
```

Also, a covering index on order_products would allow MySQL to satisfy the view query entirely from the index (EXPLAIN will show "Using index")

```
... ON order_products (orderID, psum)
```

---

(If datatype of `odate` column is DATE, then the DATE() wrapper function is unnecessary, and MySQL may be able to avoid a "Using filesort".  If the datatype is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype, that explains the use of the DATE() wrapper function.  Note that the predicate on the odate column will return rows with values between midnight of the first of the month, up to and including midnight of the 30th of the month. Typically, we'd only return entire days, and avoid excluding midnight of the 30th.

```
   AND o.odate >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
   AND o.odate <  '2014-12-30 00:00:00'
```

(My addition of the time component in the literal values is unnecessary; added just to illustrate the idea that the time component *is* considered when comparing to a datetime or timestamp.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I remove the order_products table. Now faster